# Angular - Make a button active when it is clicked and inactive when an other button in the group is clicked

Tags: typescript2.0, angular6

I got this code from this post [Adding the active class to each clicked button, Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752719/adding-the-active-class-to-each-clicked-button-angular-4?rq=1)
What I am trying to do is the same thing that is mentioned on that post, make a button active when it is clicked and make the other buttons in the group inactive.
Same code copied, for some reason it doesn't work

```
<button mat-button *ngFor="let button of filterButtons" [ngClass]="{'active': button.isClicked}" (click)="button.isClicked = !button.isClicked">
    {{ button.text }}
</button>
```

Component.ts

```
  filterButtons = [
    { text: 'Posted', isClicked: false },
    { text: 'FFM', isClicked: false },
    { text: '9999', isClicked: false },
    { text: '9000', isClicked: false },
    { text: '8555', isClicked: false },
    { text: 'Canceled', isClicked: false },
  ]
```

Comment: do you receive any error? Do you have inspected html to see if there is some change after the click? have you tried to print filterButtons variabile directly into html to see its update?

Comment: I don't receive an error, the clicked button gets active, but the other buttons in the group they are active too.

Comment: It's really strange, please provide a working example so I can reproduce your problem

Comment: Here is the stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kqxcp5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are not resetting isClicked value when you click on other buttons.

The simplest solution is something like this.

app.component.html

```
<button mat-button *ngFor="let button of filterButtons" [ngClass]="{'active': button.isClicked}" (click)="setActive(button)">
    {{ button.text }}
</button>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
    filterButtons = [
    { text: 'Posted', isClicked: false },
    { text: 'FFM', isClicked: false },
    { text: '9999', isClicked: false },
  ]


  setActive(button: any): void {
    for(let but of this.filterButtons) {
      but.isClicked = false;
    }

    button.isClicked = true;
  }
}
```

You can find other solutions, like explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50640024/angular-how-to-toggle-the-color-of-a-button-wich-is-inside-a-button-group-if-it/50640289#50640289)

Comment: Thanks @firegloves, That worked out as expected, really appreciate the instant response.